# How to read this text without any particles?

Tags: word-choice

I have a Japanese promotional postcard that has this text

料金受取人払郵便

and a box with this text in it

牛込局承認 6479

Does this say that the person receiving the postcard will pay postage followed by a permit number? That means I can mail without a stamp, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's read りょうきん (fee)・うけとりにん (recipient)・ばらい (pay)・ゆうびん (mail).

Yes, it means you can send the postcard without a stamp and the recipient will pay the fee. You can read about this service here: https://www.post.japanpost.jp/send/fee/how_to_pay/uke_cyaku/index.html